# Prove that $D$ has no prime factors $p$, where $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose the greatest common divisor of integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ is $1$. Integers $x$, $y$ and $z$ satisfy the equality $ax+by+cz=0$ and $y^2-xz=-1$.

Let $D=b^2-4ac$. Prove that $D$ has no prime factors $p$, where $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `\pmod{4}` to get $\pmod{4}$.